# Excel VBA Subscription out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I only have 2 simple lines and Excel VBA keeps telling me Subscription out of range... why?

```
Sub try_again()

'Dim res As Variant
Dim Per_Mnd As Variant
Dim Per_Mnd2 As Variant

Per_Mnd = Worksheets("Res_Lege").Range("F41:AD41")

Worksheets("Res_Kontor_over").Range("F6:AD6").Value = Per_Mnd

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't get an error. Are you positive your worksheets are named as such?

Comment: Yes, the names are correct... crazy...

Comment: Which line? And I suggest to check the names again (maybe a space somewhere a the end of the names?)

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a _subscription_ out of range?  Have you tried renewing it?  But, as @BruceWayne said - I'm not getting an error either.  Are both worksheets in the same workbook, and as Vincent suggests - double check the spelling of the sheet names.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Set Per_Mnd = Worksheets("Res_Lege").Range("F41:AD41")
Worksheets("Res_Kontor_over").Range("F6:AD6").Value = Per_Mnd.Cells(1, 1)
```

It `Set`-s `Per_Mnd` as a `Range`, thus it should be working. Then, when you are asking to put values in `Range("F6:AD6")`, it takes the first cell of `Per_Mnd` and it assigns it there.

Answer (score 0):

That would be **subscript** out of range, but never minding the typo, [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (disclaimer: I own/manage this open-source project) would fire an inspection result here:

> ```
> Per_Mnd = Worksheets("Res_Lege").Range("F41:AD41")
> ```

And another one here:

> ```
> Worksheets("Res_Kontor_over").Range("F6:AD6").Value = Per_Mnd
> ```

The inspection result would say:

> **Implicit Active Workbook Reference**
>
> *Implicit references to the active workbook make the code frail and harder to debug. Consider making these references explicit when they're intended, and prefer working off object references.*

In other words, if you're 100% sure that there's no typo in the sheet name, then it looks like the `ActiveWorkbook` isn't the workbook your code is [implicitly] assuming.

i.e. this code is exactly equivalent:

```
Per_Mnd = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Res_Lege").Range("F41:AD41").Value
```

If you mean to work with a workbook your code has opened, make sure you keep a reference to that object when you open it:

```
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(path)

'...

'now qualify the Worksheets collection with this 'wb' object:
Per_Mnd = wb.Worksheets("Res_Lege").Range("F41:AD41")
```

If you mean to work with the workbook that contains this code, qualify the `Worksheets` call with `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Per_Mnd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Res_Lege").Range("F41:AD41")
```

If the worksheet exists at compile-time, give it a *code name* (the `(Name)` property in the *properties* toolwindow /F4) instead - say, `ResLegeSheet`:

```
Per_Mnd = ResLegeSheet.Range("F41:AD41")
```